# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'School *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

I'm trying to learn how to access a constructor using array/pointers.
I know how to access class member function, but I'm stuck at how to access the constructor.

This program:
1. Ask for amount of school.
2. Ask for name of school.
3. Display each school name.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class School
{
public:
    School(string name = "")
    {   schoolname = name;}

    void Display()
    {   cout << "School name is " << schoolname;}

private:
    string schoolname;
};

int main()
{
    string sname;
    int schoolNO;
    School *myschool;
    myschool[10];

    cout << "Enter number of school : ";
    cin >> schoolNO;

    for (int i = 0; i < schoolNO; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter school name : ";
        cin >> sname;

        myschool[i] = new School(sname);*//The error stated is in this line...*
        myschool[i].Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think the line " myschool[10];" does?

Comment: Unrelated: `School *myschool; myschool[10];` the code `myschool[10];` does nothing here except build a dereference that (thankfully) is never used. You never allocate any `School` objects in this code, and thus invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's not unrelated. The confused declaration is the entire problem.

Comment: @SebastianRedl That *logic* bug is not related to the real problem that exhibits the error message: that `School` is not assignable from `School*`. Probably should have made that clearer.

Comment: @AhmadZul As written you're seemingly desiring to build an array of *pointer-to-School*, not an array of `School`. there is a difference. If you want the former, `School *myschool[10];` is the required change. If you want the latter, `School myschool[10];` is the decl (which only works if `School` is default-constructable, and it is), and the assignment is `myschool[i] = School(sname);` Personaly I'd do *neither* and use a vector, but I doubt that is an option for you.

Comment: And its worth noting (you'll figure it out eventually) that if you go the `School *myschool[10];` route, you'll need to change your `Display()` invoke to be `myschool[i]->Display();` Note the change from `.` to `->`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `mySchool` is an array of objects, not of pointers, so you cannot assign a pointer to an element of it using `new`.

Replace this:

```
School *myschool;
myschool[10];
```

For this:

```
School* myschool[10];
```

Now you have an array of pointers, and the `new` will work.

Comment: @AhmadZul `myschool[i]->Display();`

Comment: @AhmadZul Yes, but you have to access them appropriately; `myschool` wouldn't be an instance of `School`; the items contained in it are; which is sorta how you are doing it anyhow... You just need to change `myschool[i].Display();` to `myschool[i]->Display();`

Try doing this without an array first just with a pointer. And compare this to not using a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Your error has nothing to do with constructors. It has to do with incorrect declaration of your variable `mySchool`

What you are doing to setup your array isn't valid.  You want an array of size 10 of `pointers to School objects`.  You created `myschool` as a `pointer to a school`.  Additionally `myschool[10];` has no effect.

So you need to change your declaration of `School *myschool` to `School *myschools[10];`  You should also delete the bad statement I mentioned above.

*Further*, it is heavily suggested to choose names that reference the multiplicity of the object it models.  `myschool` isn't being used to point or store a single school; it's a container for multiple objects. Consider naming to be `schools` or `myschools` to make it clear to someone using it what the multiplicity of the object is.